# Magento2.2.7 PLP sorting breaks after we place orders

Tags: magento2, sorting, place-order

Whenever we place an order on store front and come back to any category page, the sorting is not working(sorting breaks) . To fix this we needed to run a reindex on the below indexers and clear the cache

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_flat
```

After running these commands , sorting works fine. But if we place next order, again it breaks and this continues.